# How to use url as a query for scraping tweets using requests and twitter API

Tags: python, twitter, python-requests, tweepy

I am trying to scrape tweets that are related to certain articles from newspapers.

So my query needs to be a link q = 'http://www.msnbc.com/rachel-maddow-show/trump-doesnt-seem-realize-he-was-outmaneuvered-mideast-deal'

When using it this way, it returns nothing. However, when using normal queries like 'trump' it works fine.

I tried both tweepy, twitter libraries and they didn't work either. What could be done ?

Here is the code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import pandas as pd 

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 

auth_params = {
    'app_key':'',
    'app_secret':'',
    'oauth_token':'',
    'oauth_token_secret':''
}

# Creating an OAuth Client connection

auth = OAuth1 (
    auth_params['app_key'],
    auth_params['app_secret'],
    auth_params['oauth_token'],
    auth_params['oauth_token_secret']
)

#that's the articles dataframe, we call it to retrieve the url of the articles, all strings.
df = pd.read_excel(open('table.xlsx','rb'), sheet_name='Sheet1')

url_rest = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json"

#list where we are supposed to save the tweets for each article 

for i in range (len(df)):
    q = df['url'][i]
    params = {'q': q, 'count': 10, 'lang': 'en',  'result_type': 'recent'}
    results = requests.get(url_rest, params=params, auth=auth)
    tweets = results.json()
    messages = [BeautifulSoup(tweet['text'], 'html5lib').get_text() for tweet in tweets['statuses']]
    y.append(messages)
```

Comment: Just to be clear, this not returning any data at all into your dataframe? have you tried using the `url:` field in your search rather than the whole URL with https etc?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Yes, it doesn't return any data. 
In fact, I don't know where to include  `url:` field in my code. I tried to put it in the query but encoded : `q= "url%3Awww.msnbc.com%252Frachel-maddow-show%252Ftrump-doesnt-seem-realize-he-was-outmaneuvered-mideast-deal"` but it didn't work. thanks